# What is the alternative to the GarbageCollector?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, garbage-collection

I have the following code, which will generate an `OutOfMemoryException` when run:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private DrawingVisual myVisual = new DrawingVisual();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myVisual = GetVisual();
        graphicsCanvas.AddVisual(myVisual);
    }

    private void Graphics_Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //get the data visual:
        DrawingVisual tempVisual = GetVisual();

        //first clear the current display data:
        graphicsCanvas.RemoveVisual(myVisual);

        //get the data visual:
        myVisual = tempVisual;

        graphicsCanvas.AddVisual(myVisual);

        //GC.Collect();
    }

    private DrawingVisual GetVisual()
    {
        double width = graphicsCanvas.ActualWidth;
        double height = graphicsCanvas.ActualHeight;

        DrawingVisual dV = new DrawingVisual();

        Rect clipRect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);

        dV.Clip = new RectangleGeometry(clipRect);

        using (DrawingContext dC = dV.RenderOpen())
        {
            RenderTargetBitmap rTB = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)width, (int)height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

            if (rTB.CanFreeze)
            {
                rTB.Freeze();
            }

            dC.DrawImage(rTB, clipRect);
        }

        return dV;
    }
}
```

Where a `Graphics_Canvas` is defined as follows:

```
class Graphics_Canvas : Canvas
{
    private List<DrawingVisual> visuals = new List<DrawingVisual>();

    protected override int VisualChildrenCount
    {
        get { return visuals.Count; }
    }

    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        return visuals[index];
    }

    public void AddVisual(DrawingVisual visual)
    {
        visuals.Add(visual);

        base.AddVisualChild(visual);
        base.AddLogicalChild(visual);
    }

    public bool ContainsVisual(DrawingVisual visual)
    {
        return visuals.Contains(visual);
    }

    public bool HasVisuals
    {
        get { return visuals.Count > 0; }
    }

    public void RemoveAllVisuals()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < visuals.Count; i++)
        {
            RemoveFromLogicalTree(visuals[i]);
        }

        visuals.Clear();
    }

    private void RemoveFromLogicalTree(Visual visual)
    {
        RemoveLogicalChild(visual);
        RemoveVisualChild(visual);
    }

    public void RemoveLastVisual()
    {
        if (visuals.Count > 0)
        {
            int index = visuals.Count - 1;

            RemoveFromLogicalTree(visuals[index]);
            visuals.Remove(visuals[index]);
        }     
    }

    public void RemoveVisual(DrawingVisual visual)
    {
        RemoveFromLogicalTree(visual);
        visuals.Remove(visual);            
    }
}
```

And the XAML to create the `Window` is like this:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:csMemoryLeakTestProject" x:Class="csMemoryLeakTestProject.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    Background="Gray"
    Height="600" Width="800"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <local:Graphics_Canvas Margin="12" Background="White" x:Name="graphicsCanvas" MouseMove="Graphics_Canvas_MouseMove"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now, this is just an example to illustrate my point, which is that I don't understand what the alternative is here to using the Garbage Collector...

If you run the program, and keep moving the mouse over the `Graphics_Canvas`, the memory use builds and builds and builds until you get an `OutOfMemoryException`. If you add in `GC.Collect()` where I've commented it out, this doesn't happen (although the memory does increase by a small amount, for reasons beyond me, and hopefully linked with my problem), and the program continues to function.

So, why does the `GC` not kick in and clear this memory and stop the exception occurring? If I'm doing some very fundamental error I'd be very happy for someone to point it out to me so that I can move beyond this.

I have seen many times on this website and others advice from programmers saying "never use the Garbage Collector". I want to conform to best practice, but I don't see in situations like this what else I could do.

Answer (score 10):

It's not a fault of `GC` that the program is not able to manage much memory. 
In your program you do:

```
private void Graphics_Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   ....
    //ADD ELEMENTS ON EVERY MOVE !
    graphicsCanvas.AddVisual(myVisual);

    //GC.Collect();
}
```

Tou add an element to every mouse move, so increase the collection size. What you would expect happen ?

So, in **90%** cases, the solution for these kind of problems, is *rearchitect* your code.

Example:

It's hardly possible that you need on MouseMove add every time a new element to a chidren collection of visual.  May be it's a case to reuse already present one.

Esplicit use of `GC` is not *suggested*, but sometimes we need to use it. But, I repeat, I can hardly believe that in *this case* you need to manage program in that way.

Comment: To be entirely honest; I find it odd, that the system would throw an `OutOfMemoryException` **before** attempting a `GC.Collect()`. Just my two-cents.

Comment: Wait, the code is first *removing* an element and then adding another. That’s fine.

Comment: @Tigran You are right, I don't need to add a Visual on MouseMove, but this is an example to quickly generate the error, that's all. Also I am removing a Visual before adding a new one, if I output the number of Visuals on the Canvas on each MouseMove it is staying constant at 1.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: removing and adding element to this collection doesn't prove anything. It doesn't mean that removed element will be removed by GC after, and it doeasn't mean that even if it suitable for remove, for some reason it will not remain in memory as passed too long generations along.

Comment: @Greg: GC collecton (esplicit or implicit) is an "order" to do collect data. It doesn't mean that it wil start immediately you call it. This means that this sample may have different behaviour on different machines, as this is everything about timing: time were element wa removed, time when were found necesary resource for check of dead referencies, time when was found resource to execute collect and time to actually collect data. I would strongly suggest to **not** rely on GC and do not push it on limits in this way. You can not predict and control it's behavior.

Comment: @Tigran: Thanks, I don't want to rely on the GC at all if I can help it, but I don't see why this program should increase in memory use given that I only add and remove a single Visual. I have a similar problem in my main program which I am trying to solve, and I thought if I could solve it in this example then I would know what the problem is.

Comment: @Tigran That wasn’t my point. My point was that this is an acceptable usage pattern that the GC will *normally* be able to take care of. Your answer strongly implies that the code is just adding objects to a collection without removing them, and that OP’s code is causing a memory leak. This is not the case.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: it adds that code on mouse move, and GC simply may not have a time to collect potentially suitable object that were removed, *if* there is any such object. My point is: it's wrong place to use that pattern.Use Add/Remove in mousemove I mean. As you can not predict delays of GC that may, and eventually *will* happen during the normal program run, which will lead to memory leaks.

Answer (score -1):

I think this describes what might be keeping your objects alive;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613565.aspx

In short; references in event handlers might still exist.

Comment: If that were the problem, calling `GC.Collect()` wouldn't fix it.

Comment: @IvoTops Yes, I have read about this. However the code posted above is the entire code for this program, and I have added no events, so I'm not sure if this could be the cause. If the Canvas adds events itself behind the scenes, what else can I do to remove them?